# Trying to get the sum of the max y values in a list of lists ( [[x,y],[x,y]......)

Tags: python

Im trying to get the sum of the max "y" of each "x" value in a list of lists.

example:

`l = [[1,29],[1,28],[2,30],[2,27]]`
For the list above , the sum result should be : 29+30 (the max y of x = 1 and the max y of x = 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to accumulate the maximum `y` per `x`:

```
l = [[1, 29], [1, 28], [2, 30], [2, 27]]

d = {}
for x, y in l:
    if x not in d:
        d[x] = y
    else:
        d[x] = max(d[x], y)


res = sum(d.values())
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
59
```

An alternative is to use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [[1, 29], [1, 28], [2, 30], [2, 27]]

d = defaultdict(lambda: float("-inf"))
for x, y in l:
   d[x] = max(d[x], y)


res = sum(d.values())
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
59
```

Note that the second approach works because:

```
float("-inf") < x
```

holds for any integer `x`. Both approaches are O(n).

**UPDATE**

If the number of unique values of `x` is small (and represent a set of contiguous indices), a third alternative is to use a list instead of dictionary to store the maximum `y` as below:

```
l = [[1, 29], [1, 28], [2, 30], [2, 27]]

cols = 2
d = [0 for _ in range(8)]  # here 8 is the number of columns in your game 
for x, y in l:
   d[x - 1] = max(d[x - 1], y)

res = sum(d)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
59
```

Note that this alternatives works assuming the `y` values are always positives (as one would expect for the columns of a game of Tetris).

Comment: This is the most efficient way! Requires to read only once the list. +1

Comment: In fact , I posted this to try to understand the way it works on list of lists  because im creating an AI bot to play Tetris and im trying to create a function to return the updated aggregated height of the game(sum of the height of all columns). Do you think this will help me create the best option for the function?

Comment: It will depend on the number of columns

Comment: I guess it will work but as my "column height" is always updating it doesnt work that well. I got 8 collumns on my Tetris board

Comment: First of all , thanks for your help! It works just well but in fact I noticed that i need the "min" instead of the "max", because if im using the max and it gets a tetromino above, the height of that column never updates because my "max" is located in the last grid.

Comment: I tried to replace the max for min but I saw that is not that simple –

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[1,29],[1,28],[2,30],[2,27]]

def maxYofX(l, x):
    return max([li for li in l if li[0] == x], key=lambda li: li[1])

s = sum([maxYofX(l, xi)[1] for xi in set( [li[0] for li in l] )])
print(s)
```